# Likelihood of a function being inlined depending on where it is defined in C++

Tags: c++, inline

I was writing a Vector class (in the maths sense, not in the `std::vector` sense) when I got thinking about the probability of the class' methods being inlined, depending on how the function is defined.

I am interested in the following cases:

**Case 1**, the function body is defined at the place of declaration in the header file. e.g.

```
// Vector.h
class Vector
{
public:
    // Other stuff up here

    float Magnitude(void) const
    {
        return sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
    }

    // Other stuff down here
}
```

**Case 2**, the function body is defined in the header file after the initial class definition. e.g.

```
// Vector.h
class Vector
{
public:
    // Other stuff up here

    float Magnitude(void) const;

    // Other stuff down here
}

// Other stuff up here

float Vector::Magnitude(void) const
{
    return sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
}

// Other stuff down here
```

**Case 3**, the function body is provided in a corresponding `.cpp` file, leaving the declaration and definition separate. e.g.

```
// Vector.h
class Vector
{
public:
    // Other stuff up here

    float Magnitude(void) const;

    // Other stuff down here
}

//Vector.cpp
#include "Vector.h"

// Other stuff up here

float Vector::Magnitude(void) const
{
    return sqrt(X*X + Y*Y);
}

// Other stuff down here
```

**Case 4**, the function definition is provided in a corresponding `.lib` file provided as compiler input.

**Case 5**, the function definition is provided in a corresponding `.dll`file linked.

In each of these 5 cases, what is the probability of the function being inlined? I don't mean an exact probability, I mean in comparison to each other, which are more likely to be inlined and which are less likely?

Other Information:

I am purposely ignoring the `inline` keyword to simplify the question so it is not too broad. I am aware that there are many other questions that tackle inlining but I could not find enough information about each case to tackle this question in particular. Also, I am aware libraries already exist with vector classes pre-made, that's not the point of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly depends on compiler, cause they are free to inline any function.

1) Only in first case it will try to automatically inline function, so  it is redundant, to add the `inline` keyword.

2) In cases 2-3 you will have to add `inline` keyword and then *maybe* it will be inlined. (Still depends on compiler)

3) In cases 4 and 5 there is no way function can be inlined since the code for `.lib` and `.dll` is already compiled. (And `.dll` even loads only in runtime!)

Also many compilers support an option that lets them automatically inline any suitable function (`-O3` in `gcc`).